# Change the state of DB thru GET?

Tags: php

**addCategory.php**

```
<?php
$parentId = isset($_GET['parentId']) ? $_GET['parentId'] : 0;

$categoryName = $categoryDescription = "";
$fail = "";


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

    if (isset($_POST['categoryName']))
        $categoryName = fix_string($_POST['categoryName']);

    if (isset($_POST['categoryDescription']))
        $categoryDescription = fix_string($_POST['categoryDescription']);

    $hidParentId = $_POST['hidParentId'];
}

$fail  = validate_category_name($categoryName);
$fail .= validate_category_description($categoryDescription);


echo "<html><head><title>An Example Form</title>";

if ($fail == "") {
  echo "success";

    header("Location: processCategory.php?action=add&categoryName=$categoryName&categoryDescription=$categoryDescription&hidparentId=$hidParentId");

    exit;
}

// Now output the HTML and JavaScript code
?>

<!-- The HTML section -->

<style>.signup { border: 1px solid #999999;
    font: normal 14px helvetica; color:#444444; }</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(form)
{

    fail  = validateCategoryName(form.categoryName.value)
    fail += validateCategoryDescription(form.categoryDescription.value)

    if (fail == "") return true
    else { alert(fail); return false }
}
</script></head><body>
<table class="signup" border="0" cellpadding="2"
    cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
<th colspan="2" align="center">Add Category</th>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>

<tr><td colspan="2">Sorry, the following errors were found<br />
in your form: <p><font color=red size=1><i><?php echo $fail ?></i></font></p>
</td></tr>

<?php 
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?parentId=<?php echo $parentId; ?>"
    onSubmit="return validate(this)">
     <tr><td>Category Name</td><td><input type="text" maxlength="32"
    name="categoryName" value="<?php echo $categoryName; ?>" /></td>
    </tr><tr><td>Category Description</td><td><input type="text" maxlength="32"
    name="categoryDescription" value="<?php echo $categoryDescription; ?>" /></td>

    <input type="hidden" name="hidparentId" value="<?php echo $parentId; ?>" />

</tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ok" /></td>
</tr></form></table>

<!-- The JavaScript section -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateCategoryName(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No name entered.\n"
    return ""
}

function validateCategoryDescription(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No description entered.\n"
    return ""
}

</script></body></html>

<?php
// Finally, here are the PHP functions

function validate_category_name($field) {
    if ($field == "") return "No name entered<br />";
    return "";
}

function validate_category_description($field) {
    if ($field == "") return "No description entered<br />";
    return "";
}

function fix_string($string) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
    return htmlentities ($string);
}

?>
```

**processCategory.php**

```
<?php
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
switch ($action) {

    case 'add' :
        addCategory();
        break;

    case 'modify' :
        modifyCategory();
        break;

    case 'delete' :
        deleteCategory();
        break;

    default :
        // if action is not defined or unknown
        // move to main category page
        header('Location: index.php');
}


/*
    Add a category
*/
function addCategory() {



    $name        = $_GET['categoryName'];
    $description = $_GET['categoryDescription'];
    $parentId  = $_GET['hidparentId'];

    $sql   =  "INSERT INTO tbl_category (cat_parent_id, cat_name, cat_description) 
            VALUES ($parentId, '$name', '$description')";
    $result = dbQuery($sql) or die('Cannot add category' . mysql_error());

    header('Location: index.php?catId=' . $parentId);     

}

function modifyCategory() {

}

function deleteCategory() {

}

?>
```

Notice here that I get the user inputs thru POST then send that POST data to same .php file......then after validation send those data to another .php file THRU GET.....insert those GET data to the DB then after inserting those data we redirect to another page.

I read that if your changing the state of the database you should use POST not GET. My idea that it is bad because GET data can be seen in the URL so users can change the state of the database in the URL, another is when you click refresh if you use POST then the browser will warn you that your trying to repeat the same method again, BUT if you use GET the browser will not warn you so end up posting the same data twice.

In my code there is no way the user can manipulate the url to change the DB because as soon as the data is inserted we redirect to different page, and also the refresh problem is not a problem here.

I want to a place separated where I process my inputs and that is processCategory.php.

Im a noob please tell me if im dooing right.

Comment: "In my code there is no way the user can manipulate the url to change the DB because as soon as the data is inserted we redirect to different page" is a very dangerous idea to have. The user is in control of their browser, and they can observe requests it makes. Your web server is just a server out there on the internet listening to HTTP requests on port 80 and spitting out responses. Users can make whatever requests they want to the web server, and it's up to the server to perform validation on every single request to make sure the data is reasonable to act upon.

Comment: **Watch out!**  HTTP GET requests should be "idempotent" -- that is, they should never have any side effects.  Making changes to data is a side effect.  You should *only* use POST for this, not GET.

Comment: But I want a place to process my data and that is processCategory.php and I want to validate the data to same page first before insert those to database. But I cant redirect with post request.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how the data gets there, it can be modified enroute. You can put it in GET or POST and the user could falsify it, make their own request, or someone in the middle could modify it (unless you run https).

Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection in your addCategory function. You should modify it at the very minimum like so:

```
function addCategory() {
    $name        = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['categoryName']);
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['categoryDescription']);
    $parentId  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hidparentId']);

    $sql   =  "INSERT INTO tbl_category (cat_parent_id, cat_name, cat_description) 
            VALUES ($parentId, '$name', '$description')";
...
```

Someone could put a part of an SQL query into any of those $_GET (or $_POST...it doesn't matter which) and possibly have it execute on your server. `mysql_real_escape_string` is a function provided for you so to make sure any parts of queries that may come in to your script by malicious users don't get through. Illustration here: http://xkcd.com/327/

Also, you may want to look up using PDOs and parameterized queries as these are even safer.

As for the user modifying things and re-submitting, you can prevent this by use of Nonces. A nonce is a security thing which is a "**n** umber used **once**". A super simple way to do this could be as follows: When you show the user the form, you should put a number of some sort into your database and then put that number into a hidden field on your form. When the user submits, the script sees the nonce in your field, checks to see if it is in the database, and deletes it. If the script couldn't find the nonce, it knows its already been used and so it rejects the user's request since that request already was processed. To further secure this, place the user's id in the database (assuming you have some sort of session handling which gives users ids) along with the nonce so that the user has his own nonce. Even better would be to give each session a unique id and use that along with the nonce. While this system isn't perfect, it should at least help in the case where a user accidentally refreshes a page. You could think of it as a "request id" and once the "request id" has been processed, it can't be processed again.

Again, it doesn't matter where you put the data so long as you validate it in some way. One restriction, however, is that some browsers (like some versions of IE) tend to not allow URLs longer than 2048 characters or so. POST data is generally not nearly as limited (except by PHP itself) and so if you plan on sending lots of data (like a post on a forum) you would probably want to use POST. If you are sending very little data (like a tweet) you could use GET. Also, passwords shouldn't be sent over GET since the user's browser may keep that in its history and you wouldn't want passwords floating around in histories everywhere...

EDIT: As a side note, you don't necessarily have to have two separate URLs to process your data. You can just remove any HTML parts from processCategory.php, use `require processCategory.php` at the top of your addCategory.php and instead of that line where you do the redirect header, replace it with something like:

```
addCategory();
header("Location: someSuccessPage.php");
```

Its not a big deal, but using too many redirects and requests can slow your site down a bit and also cause your server to take more requests than it needs to. Each time you change the Location header it sends out a 302 which makes the user's browser request another URL from the server.

Comment: I sanitize the user input first thru fix_string() then redirect those data if those data are sanitize then why sanitize them again?

Comment: When you do that Location: header, you are actually telling the user's browser to go to that page. At that point, someone could tell their browser to pause and modify the URL, making it unsanitary again. A good rule of thumb is to never ever ever trust anything coming out of $_GET or $_POST.

Comment: so your saying that you can manipulate the database thru $_GET? bacause i read somewher that if you manipulate the data then you should use $_POST. Manupulating the database means inserting and deleting data in the database.

Comment: It is all preference and convention. There isn't a set rule (but everyone will argue one way or the other). My personal preference is to follow what is called the RESTful convention: GET requests get things from the database, POST requests post (add) data, PUT modifies, and DELETE deletes. It doesn't matter which convention you use, just so long as you understand how it is going to work. Also keep in mind that for GET requests only, the browser's history might cache it so only put things there you wouldn't mind seeing in a history file.

Comment: I do think it is a little messy with all the redirects (no offense intended) and I would structure it differently, but that doesn't mean my way is the only way. If it were me, I would use POST for modifying the data since that follows the RESTful convention. Using GET isn't any worse (and some places that track views using PHP do modify the database on GET requests). If you want to make your code fit in more with a standard, look into using a templating engine (Savant3 is my favorite) or a framework (CakePHP and Drupal are popular ones).

Comment: if I follow the restful convention should I also sanitize the data coming from $_GET?? because the data didnt modify the state in the database so why sanitize it???? mysql_query() and mysqli_query() can only execute single sql statement so name'); DROP TABLE students -- ? wont work.

Comment: If the data finds its way into your query, you must sanitize it. If it doesn't get into the query, there really isn't a need unless it is shown to the user (look up cross site scripting attacks). Also, doing DROP table isn't the only thing that people can do with SQL injection and so you always assume they can find a vulnerability in your query or in PHP itself. Even if mysql_query can't execute multiple queries, who's to say an attacker can't figure out how to trick it.

Comment: if inside the database there is ' and if you search ' then you sanitize ' will you get '? sorry im a noob

Comment: It should work since all it would do with that is escape the character. You could always try and see.